# Pretrained model implemetation for NLP tasks. How to speed up the process?

Tags: python, nlp, bert-language-model

I have a huge reviews data base (around 1.5 million on different products). The database does not have predefined sentiment column, so I am doing it in an unsupervised way.

I want to get the numeric evaluation of the sentiment for each line, and therefore I am implementing this pretrained model.
**bert-base-multilingual-uncased-sentiment**

It always takes more than 4 hours to run such model on the huge dataset.
What approach might speed up the process?

I cleaned the reviews, deleted all numeric data, and stop words.

Comment: Please add what you've tried so far, it'd help others to suggest optimization solutions.

Comment: what i tried? basic: cleaning the html, url, mentions, numbers, stopwords, punctuations.

Comment: then, i increased a lot token_size in the model so it's not cutting at 512 token.